# serverless-webpack can't resolve module

Tags: webpack, serverless, serverless-webpack-plugin

Getting this error from serverless-webpack:

```
ERROR in ../db/actions/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'amazon-dax-client' in '/var/task/db/actions'
 @ ../db/actions/index.js 2:24-52
 @ ../db/db.js
 @ ./crop.js
```

My webpack.config.js file contains:

```
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: slsw.lib.entries,
    target: 'node',
    externals: {
        sharp: 'commonjs sharp',
    },
    // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: __dirname,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }]
    }
}
```

The `amazon-dax-client` module is present in node_modules.

I've rolled back to the last versions of webpack and serverless-webpack that worked for me:

```
"serverless-webpack": "4.3.0",
"webpack": "3.11.0"
```

Any ideas on how to resolve or to get additional logging output to track down the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may consider using [node-prune](https://github.com/tj/node-prune) to remove unnecessary files from node_modules (.md, .ts, ...) It would not be as effective as webpack but it's way less complicated and definitely not error-prone. It can be good enough for certain projects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the /node_modules/ exclusion? If that's removed, I'd imagine it'd be able to get into that folder and do what you need. Since amazon-dax-client is in that folder, and you're telling webpack to ignore the node_modules folder, it won't be able to reach it. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I commented out that line, and got the same result.

Comment: Can you share your file structure with me and point out your entry point? I have an idea as to what might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no longer getting the error, although I can't say specifically what fixed it.  Deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` seemed to be the catalyst.